# Default password for MySQL connection in Python

Tags: python, mysql, localhost, database-connection, mysql-connector

I installed MySQL with `pip install mysql-connector-python`.

But for connecting in Python I don't know what password to use.

mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="",password="",database="")

Comment: Did you install mysql database server too?

Comment: The password is by default `root`

Comment: The password is not defined by the database adapter, it is defined by the MySQL server.

Comment: How install mysql for python? i use this command but get error pip install MySQL-python,

Answer (score 0):

Don't use password, just use host.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html

(Btw. this is just connecting package, you need MySql server too - https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "just use host"? On the page you linked to I can find the following: "Authentication with MySQL typically uses a `username` and `password`."

Comment: @Matthias Look at Table 7.1 - Default values

Comment: I don't get it. user and password have no default values, so they are clearly missing if I don't provide them. One could omit `host` if it's running on localhost (aka 127.0.0.1), but one has to provide user and password.